# How to determine the length of a string?

Tags: python, string, integer

I have a code who transforms a csv table in an different csv table, for example the numbers in the file are shortened and written to a new file. All numbers who are longer than seven digits have to be ignored from the programm.

I tried to fix it, with following code:

```
if lineSplit[2] > len(7)
    ...
else:
    continue
```

This leads to an error that a "len" cannot be used on an "int".
I also tried to make a string for the `lineSplit`:

```
str(lineSplit[2])
```

or a with a variable like that:

```
a = lineSplit[2]
str(a) > len(7)
```

But none of this works.

Comment: Try with ```len(lineSplit[2]) > 7```, the ```len(7)``` part of your code doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if lineSplit[2] > len(7):
    ...
else:
    continue
```

The `len()` is used with `str` or any object type other than `int`, the 7 is already an int that is why it is causing error, remove the `len()` around 7. Secondly `lineSplit[2]` is a string, we should get the length of characters if we use `len()` around it. So try the following code:

```
len(lineSplit[2]) > 7
```

Comment: Please format your answers properly. Also, this _" len() is used with str **or any object type other than int**"_ is not true.